# How to consistently print data from serial in python

Tags: python, macos, arduino

I'm trying to print the data that comes across the serial from an Arduino but I am unable to do so.  My attempted code is this:

```
import serial
import time
s = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbmodemfd141',9600)

while 1:
   if s.inWaiting():
      val = s.readline(s.inWaiting())
      print val
```

Yet after about 30 lines or so are spit out I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "py_test.py", line 7, in <module>
    val = s.readline(s.inWaiting())
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/serial/serialposix.py", line 460, in read
serial.serialutil.SerialException: device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected?)
```

I imagine I am using inWaiting incorrectly, but I do not see how to use it any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried wrapping the readline in a try/except SerialException block? You could then just pass on the SerialException. It could be an issue with the serial driver reporting data in the receive buffer when there is not any, in which case your code will just keep running. Not a great fix, but it may lead you to the correct solution.

```
try:
    s.read(s.inWaiting())
except serial.serialutil.SerialException:
    pass # or maybe print s.inWaiting() to identify out how many chars the driver thinks there is
```

Comment: SerialException actually caused another error as Python said that exception did not exist.  Still, if I simply have this as an exception with no labeled exception it works.

Comment: Oh, sorry, you have to fully qualify the namespace of SerialException. I corrected the code above. Also, poster @TomK below is correct, you want to simply read() for number of bytes in the receive buffer. Line buffered reads are probably not appropriate. I would still be interested to know how many chars are "inWaiting" when this exception occurs for you (print s.inWaiting() in the except block)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to use function read(), not readline(). You are retrieving the number of characters in the buffer, they don't necessarily end with a new-line

Your loop becomes:

```
while 1:
   if s.inWaiting():
      val = s.read(s.inWaiting())
      print val
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to simply print the data coming out of the serially connected device.you can 
simply do it by using **readline()**.
first open the port by using **open()** then you need to use the **readline()**.

note:**/dev/ttyUSB0 is a port number for linux and com0 is windows**

here is the code

```py
import serial 

BAUDRATE = 115200
device_name = "ttyUSB0"
tty = device_name
s = serial.Serial("/dev/" + tty, baudrate=BAUDRATE)

s.open()
print s

try:
    while True:
        line = s.readline()   //after this you can give the sleep time also as time.sleep(1) before that import time module.
        print line
finally:
    s.close()
```